# Only make camera follow player on x axis?

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I need a script to make the camera follow the player but only on the x axis so its like mario  where when I jump the camera doesnt go up.

Answer (score 3):

Attach a new script to the camera and add something like this:

```
public Transform targetTransform;
Vector3 tempVec3 = new Vector3();

LateUpdate() {
    tempVec3.x = targetTransform.position.x;
    tempVec3.y = this.transform.position.y;
    tempVec3.z = this.transform.position.z;
    this.transform.position = tempVec3;
}
```

Set the `targetTransform` in the inspector to the player object.

It's using `LateUpdate` so that the position is updated after the player position has been updated. And it's using a local `tempVec3` variable so you're not creating a new Vector3 every frame.

Comment: C# structs like `Vector3` are value types, and since we're not dealing with strings, we don't really gain anything by defining `tempVec3` as a member variable. Just using it as a local variable in LateUpdate will put it on the stack, without allocation or garbage collection overhead like we might see with reference types, or in languages like ActionScript.

Comment: Valid point. I think it helps a little with the readability, so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way I could think of. Attach below to the camera

```
//define player game object
public GameObject player;

//wait for lateupdate
void LateUpdate()
  {
   transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, 0f, -10f);
  }
}
```

You can adjust your y and z values to your actual needs to hold the camera on those axis.
You can also attach an if statement to stop following after x reaches a certain value. E.G. at end of the level where you don't want the camera to go past a certain point.

```
//define player game object
public GameObject player;

//wait for lateupdate
void LateUpdate()
  {
   //define start and end of level. 
   //This will detach the camera from the player until it enters the range again

     if(player.transform.position.x > 0f && player.transform.position.x < 10f)
     {
         transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, 0f, -10f);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to not attach the camera object to the player directly. Instead of that I write a CameraController script which references the player and corrects the position of the camera in its `Update` method. This allows you to do things like lazy scrolling (don't scroll until the player gets close to the screen border), smooth scrolling (dampen the camera movement so erratic player movements do not translate to camera shaking) or temporarily take control of the camera and have it focus on something else.

Following the player on just one axis is another use-case for such a script.

Answer (score -2):

This is the easiest way i think,

```
public Transform player;



void Update () {


transform.position = new Vector2(player.position.x, 0f);
```

Comment: What is different and better here than the similar answers that have been posted before?